# Convert minimax to a single constrained maximization

Tags: reference-request, optimization, solution-verification, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

I have a minimax problem that I wish to convert to a single maximization problem. I am wondering if the approach is standard and, if so, if someone can point me to a reference.

Consider the following problem

$$V(x) = \min_{y}\max\{f(x,y),g(x,y)\}$$

Consider the reformulation of the inner maximization problem

$$\min_z \{z\} \text{ subject to } f(x,y)\le z, g(x,y)\le z$$

Taking a partial Lagrangian, the above can be written as

$$\max_{\lambda\ge0}\big\{\min_{z}\{z + \lambda(g(x,y)-z)\} \text{ subject to } f(x,y)\le z\big\}$$

So the problem is equivalently

$$V(x) = \max_{\lambda\ge0,\{(y,z):z\ge f(x,y)\}}\{\lambda(z-g(x,y))-z\}$$

**Question:** Is there something I missed?

Comment: When you take the partial Lagrangian (dualize the second constraint), do you mean to replace $\min_{\lambda \geq 0}$ with an inner $\sup_{\lambda \geq 0}$?

Comment: @madnessweasley Thanks, I've edited the question.